# delete duplicate items from one dataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

can anyone help me with my code I am trying to delete duplicate items from freeTechslist dataTable if the same item is included in  assignedtechsList Datatable

```
DataTable freeTechslist = user.GetAllUsers();
DataTable assignedtechsList  = Task.GetAllAssignedUserToTask(taskID);

foreach(DataRow row1 in freeTechslist.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataRow row2 in assignedtechsList.Rows)
    {
        var arr1 = row1.ItemArray;
        var arr2 = row2.ItemArray;
        if (arr2.SequenceEqual(arr1))
        {
            int num =  arr1.Count();
            freeTechslist.Rows[num].Delete();       
        }
    }
}

return freeTechslist;
```

Comment: Is there a column that acts like an ID/Key? If so, how is it named?

Comment: using Linq and Distinct won't help?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small program using LinqPad to help explain what the Linq is doing.  The implementation of `GetAllUsers` and `GetAllAssignedUserToTask` are not important for explanatory purposes; I just created sample functions to return DataTables like you are using in your code.  I also modified the code to use Guids as identifiers for techs.

```
void Main()
{
    var allTechs = GetAllUsers();   
    var freeTechsList = 
            //Start the Linq query by selecting all the available techs.
            //Since GetAllUsers returns a DataTable, we use AsEnumerable
            //to convert the DataTable to a queryable object
            from tech in allTechs.AsEnumerable()
            //Now we add a where clause to the Linq query.  Essentially 
            //what this clause does is just remove every tech that is in
            //the assigned techs list (which is returned by GetAllAssignedUserToTask)
            where 
            !(
                //This is our subquery; all this does is give us a list of Guids
                //that identifies techs that are assigned.  Again, GetAllAssignedUserToTask
                //returns a DataTable, so we use AsEnumerable to make it queryable with Linq
                from assigned in GetAllAssignedUserToTask(allTechs).AsEnumerable()
                select assigned.Field<Guid>("TechGUID")
            //The above subquery has returned us a list of assigned techs, so we check if 
            //the current tech we're looking at from GetAllUsers is in that list using 
            //the Contains method.  Contains will tell us whether the current tech is in the 
            //list of assigned techs.  Since we negate the result above (using !), that means
            //that if the tech is in this list, he will not be included in the final result.
            ).Contains(tech.Field<Guid>("TechGUID"))
            //Finally, we return the selected techs that have been filtered by our where clause
            select tech; 

    //Dump is basically just LinqPad's version of print so we can see the result.           
    freeTechsList.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
DataTable GetAllUsers()
{
    //create a datatable
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() {DataType = typeof(Guid), ColumnName = "TechGUID"});
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() {DataType = typeof(String), ColumnName = "Name"});

    //add some data
    DataRow bob = dt.NewRow();
    bob["Name"] = "Bob";
    bob["TechGUID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
    dt.Rows.Add(bob);

    DataRow phil = dt.NewRow();
    phil["Name"] = "Phil";
    phil["TechGUID"] = Guid.NewGuid();  
    dt.Rows.Add(phil);

    DataRow joe = dt.NewRow();
    joe["Name"] = "Joe";
    joe["TechGUID"] = Guid.NewGuid();   
    dt.Rows.Add(joe);

    return dt;

}

DataTable GetAllAssignedUserToTask(DataTable allUsers)
{
    //simulate Joe as our only assigned Tech
    return allUsers.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(tech => tech.Field<String>("Name") == "Joe")
                   .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: primitive identifier is guid and I really can't follow your code LINQ

Comment: I added significant comments to the query and changed it to use Guids as ids for the techs.